# undefined reference and strange content of static library

Tags: c++, android, gcc, opencv

Hey, I'm a real gcc newbee so excuse me if this is a silly question.

I want to use opencv in android and therefore try to compile it into a static library that get's used in the android ndk build process to build a shared library that I intent to use for my android app. The build of the statc library works fine, but when building the shared library I get complaints about undefined references. Since the file seemed to be correctly compiled and included I checked with ar -tv and see the following:

```
---------       0/0         27304 Jun 16 18:15 2010 /  
---------       0/0            24 Jan  1 01:00 1970 //  
rw-r--r--     501/501       11192 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxalloc.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      289760 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxarithm.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      197368 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxarray.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      335112 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxcmp.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      422872 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxconvert.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      127160 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxcopy.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      191208 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxdatastructs.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      141536 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxdrawing.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      170936 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxdxt.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501       29008 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxerror.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501       48304 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cximage.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501       23376 Jun 16 18:13 2010 /0  
rw-r--r--     501/501       61024 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxlogic.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501       39520 Jun 16 18:13 2010 cxlut.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      122064 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxmathfuncs.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      600368 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxmatmul.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      135824 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxmatrix.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      140464 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxmean.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      339224 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxmeansdv.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      118208 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxminmaxloc.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      497760 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxnorm.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      119712 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxouttext.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      346624 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxpersistence.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501        1688 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxprecomp.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501       86856 Jun 16 18:14 2010 cxrand.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      242768 Jun 16 18:15 2010 cxsumpixels.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501       82320 Jun 16 18:15 2010 cxsvd.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501      102024 Jun 16 18:15 2010 cxswitcher.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501        5968 Jun 16 18:15 2010 cxtables.o/  
rw-r--r--     501/501       43720 Jun 16 18:15 2010 cxutils.o/
```

There are two lines that I don't understand, the second one with the date 1970 and the one with \0 as filename. I also wondered because nm doesn't return anything. When I try a randlib I get:

```
ranlib: warning for library: libcxcore.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
```

The file that should figure at the place of \0 is the one that defines one of the functions that can not be referenced.

I tried this under OS X 10.6 and Ubuntu 10.04.

Any insights on this or what else I could do to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the command you use to create the static lib is wrong ? You should use "ar -rs". The "s" option create an index table. That might be your problem ?

Comment: turns out it works in ubuntu, no idea what's the problem in os x